# JDateChooser setDateFormat while input into database

Tags: java, netbeans, jdatechooser

```
ps.setString(26, ((JTextField) Birthday.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
```

That is my code how can i Convert the date format into MMM d, yyyy because the default format of my JDateChooser is yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat`, but why not store the `Date` as a `Date` in the database?

Comment: Get the `Date` value from the `JDateChooser#getDate`, use this to store the value in the database, you may need to create a `java.sql.Date` value from it though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
ps.setString(26, f.format(((JTextField) Birthday.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText()));
```

**CORRECTION**

```
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy");
ps.setString(26, f.format(Birthday.getDate()));
```

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date` - You can't `format` a `String` value

Comment: @MadProgrammer I am sorry I did not see the whole code. what is the type of `Birthday` object.

Comment: I still want to know why the OP isn't storing the date value as a date

Comment: by the way what is the type of the `ps` object?

Comment: Like a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: do you want to use `ps.setDate()` method?

Comment: I don't, but I think the OP should, as this would make it simpler to store the value without needing to mess with the date format

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about you comment about " make it simpler to store the value ". like what you want actually?

Comment: First, remember, I'm not the person who posted the question.  The OP should be storing date information as a date type, allowing for time zones and the such, rather the storing it as a `String` where everybody who wants to read the data will need to know the format it's stored and the time zone it originated from just so they can read it properly.

Comment: @madprogrammer firstly I am sorry for mistaking you as the person asking the question. After you pointed out I noticed it. What you have pointed out is perfectly correct and it would always be advisable to use `setDate` method of the `PreparedStatement` in the database column should be of type `DATE` to accomodate for the same and store the correct data.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. i just want to change the format of the date.

Comment: i try the code that you answer but it's not saving in the database

Comment: oh sorry its working now.. i tried the Correction code..
THANK YOU!

Comment: I can't vote up on your answer because im new in this website